# Azure Recurring Logic Apps not firing (weekly and Monthly)

Tags: azure

I have some Azure  recurring Logic Apps setup to run. I have a daily that is working fine and two weekly and one monthly.  The only one that works is the daily.  The others are just not firing.

Does anyone know if they are having issues with Recurring Logic Apps that specify as weekly/monthly?